# How to load a Text file into Tmemo(Android,C++Builder)

Tags: android, unicode, c++builder

I use C++Builder to make an Android app.

I try to load a text file into a `TMemo`, but there is an error:

> No mapping for the Unicode charactor exists in the target multibyte code page.

I use `TDirectory::GetFiles()` to get a list of files and add them to a `TListBox`:

```
TStringDynArray list;
TSearchOption searchOption;

searchOption = TSearchOption::soAllDirectories;

list = TDirectory::GetFiles(SYS_TxtDirectory, "*.txt", searchOption);

ListBox1->Items->Clear();
for(int i=0;i<list.Length;i++)
{
    ListBox1->Items->Add(list[i]);
}
```

When I click on the ListBox, I get a filename with full path into this variable:

```
AnsiString txtFileName; //store txt filename with full path
```

I wish to load this file into a TMemo. But these codes cause the error:

Code 1:

```
Memo1->Lines->LoadFromFile(txtFileName); //<----run to here,error occurred
```

Code 2:

```
TStringStream * LrcFileStream;

LrcFileStream=new TStringStream();

LrcFileStream->LoadFromFile(txtFileName);

Memo1->Lines->LoadFromStream(LrcFileStream); //<----run to here,error occurred

delete LrcFileStream;
```

Code 3:

```
TStringDynArray list;

list = TFile::ReadAllLines(LrcFile); //<----run to here,error occurred

Memo1->Lines->Clear();

for(int i=0;i<list.Length;i++)
{
    Memo1->Lines->Add(list[i]);
}
```

Code 4:

```
TStringList *ss=new TStringList();

ss->LoadFromFile(LrcFile); //<----run to here,error occurred

for(int i=0;i<ss->Count;i++)
{
    TmpStr=TmpStr+ss->Strings[i];
}

delete ss;
```

How can I load a text file into a `TMemo`?

Comment: What character encoding is the file actually using? You are not specifying any encoding when loading the file data, so it is going to be decoded to Unicode using a default encoding (ANSI on Windows, UTF-8 on other platforms) if the file does not have a BOM. So clearly you are running into an encoding mismatch issue. You need to know the file's encoding so it can be decoded properly. Both `TStrings::LoadFrom...()` and `TFile::ReadAllLines()` have an optional `TEncoding` parameter so you can specify an explicit encoding.

Comment: Yes. I modify these codes and now it work on Android.      TStringDynArray list;
  list = TFile::ReadAllLines(LrcFile,TEncoding::ANSI);
  TmpStr="";
  Memo1->Lines->Clear();
  for(int i=0;i<list.Length;i++)
  {
   TmpStr=TmpStr+list[i];
  }

Comment: Thank Remy Lebeau.

Answer (score 0):

These codes are working on Abdroid now.

```
TStringDynArray list; 
UnicodeString TmpStr;
list = TFile::ReadAllLines(LrcFile,TEncoding::ANSI); 
TmpStr=""; 
Memo1->Lines->Clear(); 
for(int i=0;i<list.Length;i++) 
{ 
    TmpStr=TmpStr+list[i]; 
}
```